# CSS : absolute positioning of a button in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, cross-browser

I want to display a button which takes all spaces of its parent which is himself absolute positioned.

But it seems that Firefox has a bug with it (All runs perfectly in Chrome and Safari (Webkits), I can't test on IE because I'm on mac (if anyone can test and say in comment if it runs or not, it would be really nice)).

The goal to achieve is :

[image]

Div and button are together contained by a wrapper which is absolute positioned.

The HTML code is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .wrapper {
                background-color: red;
                position: absolute;
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;
            }

            .inner {
                background-color: blue;
                position: absolute;
                top: 0px;
                bottom: 0px;
                left: 0px;
                right: 0px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper" style="top: 50px; left: 50px;">
            <div class="inner">div</div>
        </div>

        <div class="wrapper" style="top: 50px; left: 200px;">
            <button class="inner">button</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

That's quite simple. The problem is that on Firefox, it renders like this :

[image]

Have you got any idea why Firefox renders this code like this and have you got any workaround using similar positioning ?

EDIT : I can't (and I don't want) set width and height on inner child. The reason is that I use GWT with layout mechanisms. GWT layout uses bottom/top/left/right to position and size elements, so I can't change this behavior. All runs with classic div. The problem is only button related.

Comment: Have you tried setting display:block?

Comment: yes I've tested just before you ask. It does nothing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it renders like this is that `<button>` is a replaced element at least in Gecko and for replaced elements the rules on what `left: 0; right: 0` means in CSS are different than they are for non-replaced elements...

Comment: ok, replaced elements seems to be the cause of this problem. Thanks ! Additional information on replaced elements : http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/replacedelements

Comment: This is explanation of problem, Is there any solution for this kind of problem? (I prefer using buttons as it aligns the text in middle).

Comment: You could use `left: 0; width: 100%;`

Answer (score 7):

Try adding

```
min-width: -moz-available;
```

to the `.inner` declaration.

I've found that it works even in Internet Explorer 7+. In IE6 it fails but it's hardly a surprise. Unfortunately it also fails in Opera exactly the way it does originally in Firefox.

Comment: This fixes the problem in firefox. Nobody cares about opera since opera is 100% unused (at least in my site) and moving to webkit!

Answer (score 3):

Set a width and height for the inner div also.

Comment: I can't use width or height because I use GWT layout mechanism which uses bottom/top/left/right to set sizes

Comment: @Jerome: How is it harder to type `width:100%` and `height:100%` than `right:0` and `bottom:0`?

Comment: Try "float:left;" instead of "position,top,bottom,left,right" in .inner.

Comment: Because I use GWT with Layout mechanisms which uses bottom/top/left/right.