# positioning in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firefox

I created a simple Sudoku design using jQuery and css. The design looks nice in Chrome as well as IE8 but not good in firefox 18.0.1.

Here is the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mwb2E/13/)**

To me, the problem seems to be in CSS styling (positioning).

```
 #main>div>div>div>button {
     margin:0;
     border:none;
     background-color:white;
     position:absolute;
     top:0.5px;
     bottom:0.5px;
     left:0.5px;
     right:0.5px;
     color:#1a1a1a;
 }
```

Please have a look at jQuery code also if you think the issue is in it.

Comment: There's no output on the Fiddle?

Comment: Why didn't you do that automatically? o.O

Comment: I did but seems to be some bug in my PC, not sure.

Comment: what do you want from code? and what is happening with code?

Comment: I already added a link to the jQuery version in the question, @Boaz.

Comment: @AspiringAqib The design is messed in firefox 18.0.1. I mean the design with buttons.

Comment: Give the buttons a fix height and width and it looks fine in firefox: ... button {display:block;width:53px;height:53px;...}

Comment: Why `0.5px`? Positioning with subpixel values will only give you trouble.

Comment: @Christoph I changed it to 1px still same problem.

Comment: this html and css are totally unreadable.  make friends with your spacebar, use classes and semantic tags instead of relying on div nesting.  also, ids aren't supposed to start with a digit.

Comment: @Eevee sorry for that, anyway I solved the problem and even posted the solution as answer. (If you click `tidyUp` in fiddle the code gets automatically indentation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because of the behaviour of Button as [**replaced elments**](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/replacedelements) in firefox (Gecko). Which I solved, by using `min-width: -moz-available;` as mentioned in this [**post**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7271936/1577396). and I even realize that my post is duplicate of that link.

```
#main>div>div>div>button
{
     min-width: -moz-available;     /* added */
     min-width: -webkit-available;  /* just added(optional for me) */
     min-width: available;          /* optional for me */
     /* other properties */
}
```

As mentioned by @axel.michel in above comments, We can give fixed width and height or else if you are not sure what could be the length, simply give `width:100%;height:100%;display:block;`.

**EDIT**: The below properties can also be used if you want to have `1px` gap to the dimensions assigned in percentages. (as mentioned by @BorisZbarsky in below comments)

```
#main>div>div>div>button
{
     width: -webkit-calc(100% - 1px);
     height: -webkit-calc(100% - 1px);
     width: -moz-calc(100% - 1px);
     height: -moz-calc(100% - 1px);
     width: calc(100% - 1px);
     height: calc(100% - 1px);
     /* other properties */
}
 //Doesn't work in IE8
```

Comment: You can use things like `width: calc(100% - 1px); left: 0.5px` for what it's worth.

Comment: @BorisZbarsky Can you please provide simple fiddle. I tried using the above but chrome is ignoring that property. http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/Mwb2E/14/

Comment: Chrome doesn't support unprefixed `calc()` yet.  Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/Mwb2E/16/